# How is the clojure.lang.Reflector used in implementation of interop methods

Tags: reflection, clojure

When we run

```
(.someMethod obj arg1 arg2 arg3)
```

is the clojure.lang.Reflector class used all the time and how does that affect performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on whether the compiler can statically determine which class or interface `someMethod` belongs to.

If it can, then it will emit a direct call and `c.l.Reflector` will not be used at runtime. The result is equivalent to

```
((Foo) obj).someMethod(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

in Java, assuming `someMethod` has been declared by the class / interface `Foo`.

If it cannot, then it will emit a call to the static method `clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod`. In Clojure notation, the emitted call could be written

```
(clojure.lang.Reflector/invokeInstanceMethod
  obj "someMethod" (object-array [arg1 arg2 arg3]))
```

This looks up the matching method through the use of reflection at runtime. The slowdown relative to a statically resolved call is quite spectacular.

Comment: When would be the case when a compiler cannot resolve the method?

Comment: When it has insufficient information about the type of `obj`. For example, if `obj` is a non-type-hinted parameter of a function, then there is no way for the compiler to figure out what `obj` might turn out to be at runtime. In fact, it's possible that the function will be used with objects of many types which all have a method called `someMethod`, but are completely unrelated. The set of all such types may even grow at runtime.